# Disable MySQL Stats on INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I disable MySQL updating statistics for INDEX's when bulk inserting? I'm trying to test the performance drop from a SELECT statement with an INDEX before and after doing a bulk insert without the statistics being updated.

Comment: What's the point? I'm having difficulty understanding the point of this exercise. Statisics influence which execution plan is selected; but they don't cause a "performance drop" of the execution. To test performance of different execution plans for a query, you could use index hints to exercise influence over the selected execution plan. [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-hints.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-hints.html). I can't fathom why you'd need or want inaccurate statistics.

Comment: @spencer7593 Disabling the meta stats can drastically improve queries against information schema. This can cause problems if you don't immediately turn them back on after the fact though. That's about the only consistently useful application of disabling them that I have encountered though.

Comment: @mopsyd: I concur about your point about `innodb_stats_on_metadata`, disabling that can significantly improve performance of queries against `information_schema`. But I don't think this disables Innodb automatic collection of statistics, the index "dives" that happen when 1/16 of the table or 2 billion rows are changed. I would be very surprised to find that automatic statistics collection would affect the performance of "bulk" insert. If Innodb statistics collection can be disabled, I don't think it would have a measurable affect on a bulk load.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MyISAM you are doing it wrong. If you are using Innnodb, Innodb will statistically (does random dives into the data set) calculate the index statistics for execution plans. You can control this but why? What are you trying to gain from poorly calculated indexing?